# postgres - Create view using a function that gives a temporary table

Tags: postgresql, function, view

I want to create a table view using a function that returns a temporary table...

For example,  I have a function.

```
create or replace function colpivot(
    out_table varchar
) returns void as $$
    declare
        in_table varchar;
    begin

    create table as select * from employees;
end;
```

Now I want to create a view using the temporary table (out_table) given by above function...

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Instead of creating a temp table, declare and return a refcursor. See the manual.

Answer (score -1):

I would modify your query as follows

```
create or replace function colpivot(
out_table varchar ) returns void as $$

begin

   select * from employees into out_table ;
   execute 'CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW newView AS ' ||  out_table;

end;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```